# Tabulator persistance is not working for toggle column

Tags: tabulator

I have requirement enable/disable the columns in the tabulator. Column is disabled using toggle method and  and i am enabling back using show method.

```
table.getColumns().forEach(col => {
if(true){
{
col.toggle();
}else{
col.show();
}
 });
```

I configured persistence mode as below

```
 persistence: {
        sort: true, //persist column sorting
        filter: true, //persist filter sorting
        columns: true, //persist columns
      
    }
```

```
 persistenceMode:  "local",
    persistentLayout:true,
```

Now problem is every time when i hide the column it works temporarily but when i reload or relogin everything comes. Expectation here is removed column should not appear. Rearranging the column order is retained after reload but not toggled one. Can some one advise how to persist the toggled column or is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: please create a link to a JS Fiddle or code pen that demonstrates how your table is setup. without seing the table configuration it is hard to offer advice

Comment: Have you tried since the patch release on the 18th Dec?